# How to center UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code for my `UIButton`. What should I change in my `CGRectMake` to set my `UIButton` in the center of the screen for all screen sizes?

```
let loginBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(60, 360, 240, 40))
loginBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
loginBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
loginBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
loginBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
loginBtn.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.view.addSubview(loginBtn)
```

Comment: I would like to know it in codes not auto layout

Comment: You can do auto layout in code. If you don't use / learn auto layout then you'll get left behind. Find a tutorial on auto layout and use that. :-)

Comment: just set the center to the view's center

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering a label in a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736287/centering-a-label-in-a-uiview)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your place uibutton center of your view , update your cgrectmake as bleow..

```
CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 240) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height - 40) / 2,240,40)
```

**or**

You can add one line after your code

```
loginBtn.center = self.view.center
```

**For SignUp Button :**

```
signup.frame = loginBtn.bounds
signup.center = CGPointMake(loginBtn.center.x, loginBtn.center.y + loginBtn.frame.size.height + 10)
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried to add that simple code after my code and it worked :)

Comment: But I have to buttons now, one for login and one for signUp and that code makes it at the centre so how do I make the signUp button just below the login button ?

Comment: @mrunalthanki  What to do if I want to set button to right?

Answer (score 3):

Set your `UIButton`'s `center` to the center of the `view` it is in.

```
loginBtn.center = view.center
```

Comment: frame also has a property called midX and midY

Comment: Thank you @LeoDabus. Wasn't aware of that property.

Comment: The super view probably also has a `center` property `loginBtn.center = view.center`

Comment: Your code worked great too, But I have to buttons now, one for login and one for signUp and that code makes it at the centre so how do I make the signUp button just below the login button ? Thanks

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary ask a new question. You should consider using Auto Layout.

Answer (score 1):

This will center the button across the whole screen, not just the view it's in:

```
let verticalCenter: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height / 2.0
let horizontalCenter: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2.0

loginBtn.center = CGPoint(x: horizontalCenter, y: verticalCenter)
```

*Edit:*

As @LeoDabus pointed out, this can be compacted by using the `midX` and `midY` properties on `CGRect`:

```
let verticalCenter: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midY
let horizontalCenter: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midX
```

Comment: bounds has a property called midX and midY.

Comment: Could you link a reference? I can't find the properties here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectGetMinX

Comment: http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/ Sorry I can't find those extension CGRect at Apple's website

Comment: extension CGRect {
    var minX: CGFloat { get }
    var minY: CGFloat { get }
    var midX: CGFloat { get }
    var midY: CGFloat { get }
    var maxX: CGFloat { get }
    var maxY: CGFloat { get }
    var width: CGFloat { get }
    var height: CGFloat { get }
}

Answer (score 1):

You need add the following line prior to `self.view.addSubview(loginBtn)`.

```
loginBtn.center = self.view.center
```

Comment: But I have to buttons now, one for login and one for signUp and that code makes it at the centre so how do I make the signUp button just below the login button ?

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4**

```
@IBOutlet weak var btStart: UIButton!
```

on the middle of any screen (any device)

```
btStart.center = self.view.center
```

**OR**

```
btStart.center.x = self.view.center.x
btStart.center.y = self.view.center.y
```

---

on the center by x and 25 percent from top

```
btStart.center.x = self.view.center.x
btStart.center.y = self.view.center.y / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the best solution for me..

**Swift 4**

```
myButton.center.x = self.view.frame.midX 
myButton.center.y = self.view.frame.midY
```

I found if I need to center things quite often, I usually use a generic solution.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func centerComponent(_ component: AnyObject) {
        let customView = component as! UIView
        customView.center.x = self.view.frame.midX
        customView.center.y = self.view.frame.midY
    }
}
```

then you can call it from any UIViewcontroller inside a function like so:

```
centerComponent(myButton)
```